# Can std::bit_cast be used to cast from std::span<A> to std::span<B> and access as if there was an array of object B?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

```
#include <array>
#include <bit>
#include <span>

struct A {
    unsigned int size;
    char* buf;
};

struct B {
    unsigned long len;
    void* data;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(sizeof(A) == sizeof(B));
    static_assert(alignof(A) == alignof(B));
    std::array<A, 10> arrayOfA;
    std::span<A> spanOfA{arrayOfA};
    std::span<B> spanOfB = std::bit_cast<std::span<B>>(spanOfA);
    // At this point, is using spanOfB standard compliant?
}
```

I've tried accessing `bit_cast`ed `span` on 3 major compilers and they seem to be working as expected, but is this standard compliant?

Comment: Reading elements of `spanOfB` has to be a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: In C++20 `std::span` is not guaranteed to be trivially copyable. This guarantee will be introduced in C++23. So the `bit_cast` may not be allowed.

Comment: Stop trying to pun types in C++. It's never legal, and it's not meant to be.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Let's be real though. `span<T>` is trivially copyable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. While `std::span` in C++23 will be defined such that it must be trivially copyable, there is no requirement that any particular `span<T>` has the same layout of `span<U>`. And even if it did, you'd still be accessing the objects of type `A` through a glvalue of type `B`, which violates strict aliasing if `A` and `B` aren't allowed to be accessed that way. And in your example, they are not.