# How do I safely, with out UB type-pun data in c++20 on aligned arbitrary words to a struct?

Tags: c++, c++20, undefined-behavior, type-punning

All data I receive and send is aligned to 4 bytes.  I know this for a fact in this messaging system.  Most questions do no deal with all ready aligned data, where both the source and destination data have the exact same alignment with no caveats, and most of the time people just jump to "use std::bitcast" and *only* look at struct to struct/primitive to primivite puns, not arbitrary data streams that must be interpreted.

I've got a UDP packet that contains an array of uint32_ts, which may be reinterpreted differently based on the message type, but will have the same alignment.

I first send a command to a socket of an arbitrary message type with uint32_t aligned data (no issue, as I can std::bit_cast to a std::array of the same size of uint32_ts), for example:

```
enum class Bar : std::uint32_t {
    A = 0u,
    B,
    C,
    D
}

struct alignas(4) Foo{
   Bar
   std::uint32_t x;
   std::uint32_t y; 
}

...
    Foo foo_command = {...};
    command_socket.send_to(
        asio::buffer(std::bit_cast<std::array<std::uint32_t, sizeof(Foo)/4>>(foo_command)),
        command_endpoint, 0, err);
...
```

then I get an associated message type back, which contains multiple structs, all aligned to 4 byte boundaries.

```
std::array<std::uint32_t, 1024> recv_buffer;
std::size_t bytes_received =  command_socket.receive(asio::buffer(recv_buffer));
```

where I might have :

```
enum class ResponseType : uint32_t{
    Ok,
    NotOk
}

struct alignas(4) Baz{
    uint32_t u;
    uint32_t i;
    uint32_t j;
    Bar a;
    Bar b;
}
```

and have the type of `recv_buffer[0]` be the same as `ResponseType`, and the rest of the values correspond to Baz.

I think I could do the same trick with bitcast that I did with sending, but the problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to get fixed size std::spans to actually compile, and it is very unclear to me, the way others have explained the standard whether or not "slicing" is defined behavior like this.

given `Baz baz_response` is it safe and defined behavior to instead do `std::memcpy(&recv_buffer[1], &baz_response, sizeof(baz))` or something similar?

Comment: `std::bitcast` is a smart and convenience wrapper around `std::memcpy`, why you just don't use that instead?

Comment: Also, on sending side, you can just `reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>` / [`std::as_bytes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/as_bytes) the data, since std:byte, char and unsigned char are allowed to alias any type with any alignment. This will remove a possible expansive copy.

Comment: @FabianKeßler How would I accomplish using std::bitcast?  std::span even with explicit size argument did not work for this case.  The other part is good info.

Comment: `std::bit_cast`, can't work with "variable sized" structures or `std::span`. `std::span` is only a container for a pointer to some data, which is also aware, that the data at the pointer is "viewable". The layout is: `struct{T* ptr; size_t size;};. Therefore, you can't `bitcast` it. You could `bit_cast` it into a fixed size `std::array` or, if the size is not known at compile time, `memcpy` it into a newly allocated std::vector;

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `std::span` together with `std::bit_cast`.
`std::bit_cast` works on objects and does a full memory copy, while `std::span` is only a container/view aware reference to continuous data.
A working copy would reinterpret the data as a pointer with its size.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918542/can-stdbit-cast-be-used-to-cast-from-stdspana-to-stdspanb-and-access-a) for a similar question regarding the bit cast of spans.

---

For your case, I would `std::memcpy` the data into the target:

```
std::array<std::byte, 1024> recv_buffer; // uint32_t is technically not allowed to alias the struct
std::size_t bytes_received =  command_socket.receive(asio::buffer(recv_buffer));

auto read_data = [&, p_iter = recv_buffer.data(), ep_iter = recv_buffer.data() + bytes_received] <class T> () mutable {
  auto new_iter = p_iter + sizeof(T);
  if(new_iter > ep_iter) std::terminate(); // error_handling 
  T t; // NOLINT(cppcoreguidelines-init-variables)
  std::memcpy(&t, p_iter, sizeof(T));
  p_iter = new_iter;
  return t; // return value optimisation
};

auto t = read_data<ResponseType>();
switch (t){
  case Ok: handleOK(read_data<Bar>()); break;
  case NotOk: handleNotOK(read_data<Baz>());break;
};
```

---

Some other way would be to just reinterpret your data, but I am actually unsure if this is still defined behavior:
I think `std::array<uint32_t, 3>` is not allowed to alias `Bar`, even if they have the same alignment. But you can make sure, that the same byte representation is used (requires same alignment) by:

`auto const& bar = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<Bar const&>(recv_buffer[1]));`

When you do this, you should test the behavior on all target systems for all compilers.